# STArray and stack overflow

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow, starray

I am struggling to understand why the following attempts to find a minimum element in STArray lead to stack space overflow when compiled with `ghc` (7.4.1, regardless of -O level), but **work fine** in `ghci`:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Array.ST

n = 1000 :: Int

minElem = runST $ do
  arr <- newArray ((1,1),(n,n)) 0 :: ST s (STArray s (Int,Int) Int)
  let ixs = [(i,j) | i <- [1..n], j <- [1..n]]
  forM_ ixs $ \(i,j) -> writeArray arr (i,j) (i*j `mod` 7927)
--  readArray arr (34,56)  -- this works OK
--  findMin1 arr           -- stackoverflows when compiled
  findMin2 arr           -- stackoverflows when compiled

findMin1 arr = do
  es <- getElems arr
  return $ minimum es

findMin2 arr = do
  e11 <- readArray arr (1,1) 
  foldM (\m ij -> min m <$> readArray arr ij) e11 ixs
      where ixs = [(i,j) | i <- [1..n], j <- [1..n]]

main = print minElem
```

Note: switching to `STUArray` or `ST.Lazy` doesn't seem to have any effect.

The main question though: What would be the proper way to implement such "fold-like" operation over big `STArray` while inside `ST`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big problem in `findMin1` is `getElems`:

```
getElems :: (MArray a e m, Ix i) => a i e -> m [e]
getElems marr = do
  (_l, _u) <- getBounds marr      -- Hmm, why is that there?
  n <- getNumElements marr
  sequence [unsafeRead marr i | i <- [0 .. n - 1]]
```

Using `sequence` on a long list is a common cause for stack overflows in monads whose `(>>=)` isn't lazy enough, since

```
sequence ms = foldr k (return []) ms
        where
          k m m' = do { x <- m; xs <- m'; return (x:xs) }
```

then it has to build a thunk of size proportional to the length of the list. `getElems` would work with the `Control.Monad.ST.Lazy`, but then the filling of the array with

```
forM_ ixs $ \(i,j) -> writeArray arr (i,j) (i*j `mod` 7927)
```

creates a huge thunk that overflows the stack. For the strict `ST` variant, you need to replace `getElems` with something that builds the list without `sequence` or - much better - compute the minimum without creating a list of elements at all. For the lazy `ST` variant, you need to ensure that the filling of the array doesn't build a huge thunk e.g. by forcing the result of the `writeArray` calls

```
let fill i j
      | i > n     = return ()
      | j > n     = fill (i+1) 1
      | otherwise = do
          () <- writeArray arr (i,j) $ (i*j `mod` 7927)
          fill i (j+1)
() <- fill 1 1
```

The problem in `findMin2` is that

```
foldM (\m ij -> min m <$> readArray arr ij) e11 ixs
```

is lazy in `m`, so it builds a huge thunk to compute the minimum. You can easily fix that by using `seq` (or a bang-pattern) to make it strict in `m`.

> The main question though: What would be the proper way to implement such "fold-like" operation over big `STArray` while inside `ST`?

Usually, you'll use the strict `ST` variant (and for types like `Int`, you should almost certainly use `STUArray`s instead of `STArray`s). Then the most important rule is that your functions be strict enough. The structure of `findMin2` is okay, the implementation is just too lazy.

If performance matters, you will often have to avoid the generic higher order functions like `foldM` and write your own loops to avoid allocating lists and control strictness exactly as the problem at hand requires.

Comment: As usual, great answer, Daniel! Any comments on why `findMin1` and `findMin2` produce the answer in `ghci`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to explain that: ghci uses an unlimited stack (since 6.10 or 6.12, iirc), so it handles huge thunks as long as they're not too big for the RAM. Compiled code runs with an 8MB stack by default.

Answer (score 5):

That's probably a result of `getElems` being a bad idea.  In this case an array is a bad idea altogether:

```
minimum (zipWith (\x y -> (x, y, mod (x*y) 7927)) [1..1000] [1..1000])
```

This one gives you the answer right away: (1, 1, 1).

If you want to use an array anyway I recommend converting the array to an `Array` or `UArray` first and then using `elems` or `assocs` on that one.  This has no additional cost, if you do it using `runSTArray` or `runSTUArray`.

Comment: Of course the actual computation is more complicated then `mod`. The point was to do computation in `ST` and then find the element satisfying some condition in the resulting array why still in `ST` (without) `freeze`. So the question stays: can we find a minimum element in STArray without converting it to `Array` or `UArray`.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the purpose of ST.  It's not to make computation faster (likely even slower), but to allow imperative constructs within pure code.  An algorithm in pure code will always outperform the same algorithm in ST.  But there are algorithms for which you *need* ST.  In this case (and most others) you don't.

Comment: "An algorithm in pure code will always outperform the same algorithm in ST" <- Umm, you mean "an algorithm that wouldn't benefit from in-place mutation", don't you?

Comment: @Daniel: Of course.  The algorithm to search for the minimum in an unordered list is a full traversal.  This does not benefit from in-place update, so a pure version is faster, because it gets along without the monadic binding.  Of course the implementation of `ST` might make binding cheap, but not free.

Comment: Yes, for the problem as it stands, it's not the right tool (Number Theory is). I was just taking issue with your formulation that read overly broad.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that minimum is a non-strict fold, so it is causing a thunk buildup.  Use (foldl' min).

Now we add a bunch of verbiage to ignore because stackoverflow has turned worthless and no longer allows posting a straightforward answer.

Comment: Well, I'd love to see straightforward working answer with `foldl'`